# PHP: Difference Between Two Dates Incorrect For March

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am having some issues with calculating the number of nights between two dates in PHP.

The problem I've found only exists for **some** dates in March (but not all, it doesn't seem to affect other months).

The Code I am using:

```
// The Calculation.
// Note: $endDate, and $startDate are unix timestamps returned from strtotime().

$diff = $endDate - $startDate;
$totalNights = floor($diff/(60*60*24));

// Debugging.                
$debugStr = "FROM " . 
    date("Y-m-d", $startDate) . 
    " - ". date("Y-m-d", $endDate) . 
    ": $totalNights Nights"; 

file_put_contents("/tmp/date_debug.txt", $debugStr . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

Here is some output from June (correct # of nights calculated):

```
FROM 2015-06-01 - 2015-06-03: 2 Nights     // Correct
FROM 2015-06-16 - 2015-06-26: 10 Nights    // Correct
FROM 2015-06-19 - 2015-06-22: 3 Nights     // Correct
FROM 2015-06-01 - 2015-06-02: 1 Nights     // Correct
FROM 2015-06-21 - 2015-06-23: 2 Nights     // Correct
FROM 2015-06-21 - 2015-06-23: 2 Nights     // Correct
FROM 2015-06-01 - 2015-06-01: 0 Nights     // Correct
FROM 2015-06-03 - 2015-06-04: 1 Nights     // Correct
FROM 2015-06-05 - 2015-06-06: 1 Nights     // Correct
FROM 2015-06-12 - 2015-06-16: 4 Nights     // Correct
FROM 2015-06-01 - 2015-06-03: 2 Nights     // Correct
FROM 2015-06-04 - 2015-06-30: 26 Nights    // Correct
```

Here is some output from March (some correct, some incorrect # of nights)

```
FROM 2015-03-05 - 2015-03-31: 25 Nights    // INCORRECT: Should Be 26 Nights 
FROM 2015-03-16 - 2015-03-19: 3 Nights     // Correct
FROM 2015-03-05 - 2015-03-10: 4 Nights     // INCORRECT: Should Be 5 Nights
FROM 2015-03-23 - 2015-03-27: 4 Nights     // Correct
FROM 2015-03-08 - 2015-03-11: 2 Nights     // INCORRECT: Should Be 3 Nights
FROM 2015-03-08 - 2015-03-19: 10 Nights    // INCORRECT: Should Be 11 Nights 
FROM 2015-03-21 - 2015-03-26: 5 Nights     // Correct
FROM 2015-03-01 - 2015-03-26: 24 Nights    // INCORRECT: Should Be 25 Nights.
FROM 2015-03-20 - 2015-03-27: 7 Nights     // Correct.
```

Any advice as to why some of these totals for March are 1 fewer than they should be would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates are not things you can just do simple math on. A Day isn't always 86400 seconds, and some days don't have 24 hours.

https://3v4l.org/LrTKb is an example of your first issue in March, done right using the DateTime objects.

Comment: Thanks. I switched these to DateTime objects.

Answer (score 2):

Of note is that all of your incorrect results include 2015-03-08 where for some time zones, DST took effect at 02:00:00, such that one hour is lost, and which is consistent with your results. You can try including:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Before any date and time calculations and see if the results are correct.

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly!

Such a simple fix for something that I've been hitting a wall with for the last several hours!